# Python abstraction-layer for SQL

Tags: python, sql, json, database, wrapper

I'm currently using Python to store files in a JSON Database. However the JSON has started to become rather large, and inefficient (reading a 20MB file, changing one value, writing 20MB back to disk again, takes rather long)

So, I was thinking about switching to SQL (SQLite or Mysql), however I don't want to change my entire code. So far, I've been reading the JSON into lists/arrays and access them rather easily

```
database["key"] = "NewValue"
```

But if I switched to SQL, I'd have to deal with long SQL queries (select from.....insert into....), apart from the entire overhead-stuff (connect, execute, etc.). That requires me to rewrite every single data-access in my code.

Is there a way (maybe some sort of wrapper), where I can just keep my existing code-base, and let the wrapper the conversion for me in the background?

Comment: This is off-topic, but you could try https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Comment: If you have consistently used the same variable name for database object then you can create a new wrapper object and assign database variable to an instance of that object. Then you can override get and set methods to ensure compatibility. But using existing ORM libraries would be better.